# How do I restrict RethinkDB access to a specific application?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rethinkdb

I have an elastic beanstalk app that uses a rethink-db instance as its database. The obvious thing to do would be to restrict access to the the database to only this application.

But if I set the relevant port in the security group of the Rethinkdb instance to anything other than 0.0.0.0, the application can't reach the DB.

The application is using the private DNS of the database for resolution and is in the same amazon region... as far as I understand, this alone should already get me passt the security group without any rules. Not in this case, apparently.

I have tried adding an exception for the applications security group to the databases security group on that port, as well as the security group of the load balancer of the application. I have also tried both at the same time. No dice.

The beanstalk-app is scalable, so it usually communicates from several instances that can change at a whim. Going over an elastic IP and allowing that in the databases security group is therefore not an option, unfortunately.

In the end, I'm forced to leave the security group of the rethink db on the driver port wide open at 0.0.0.0... Anything else I've tried made it unreachable for my own application.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as far as I understand, this alone should already get me passt the
>   security group without any rules

That's not correct. You always have to have a security group rule to allow access. All inbound traffic is blocked by default.

> I have tried adding an exception for the applications security group
>   to the databases security group on that port

That sounds like exactly what you need to do. You need to create an inbound rule in the security group assigned to the database server. In that rule you would specify the ID of the security group that the Elastic Beanstalk instances belong to.

If that isn't working, then you might need to post more information in your question, like the actual security group settings.

Also, you need to make sure your EB instances are trying to connect to the database server via the private IP of the DB server. Your issue sounds like maybe they are using the public IP of the DB server. I know you said they are using the private DNS of the DB server, but you need to make certain that is the case, and make certain that DNS is correctly resolving to the private IP, when referenced from the EB instances.

Comment: Interesting... after your emphasis on the private IP I changed the app to explicitly use the IP instead of the DNS... and now it works. Thanks! I thought the private DNS should always resolve to the private IP when the instances are in the same region?

Comment: Yes, the private DNS should resolve to the private IP.  That's strange that it isn't. Are you sure DNS lookups are working on your EB servers? I'd try running `nslookup your-db-private-dns` to see what comes back.

Comment: I can't confirm on the EB instance itself, since they don't have a key, but other instances in the region seem to resolve the DNS correctly. Buuut... I just realised that the DB is running on a t2 instance, while lein elastic beanstalk deploys the app to a t1 instance. Might be part of the problem, although they're still in the same VPC and the resolution works correctly the other way around (from a t2 to a t1 instance).

Comment: Instance type should have no bearing on that at all, as long as they are in the same VPC. In general I would recommend having SSH keys on all instances. I understand you don't want to enable someone to make manual changes on EB instances, but now you can't login to them to debug networking issues like this.